# Function failing when combining large CSV files together into single Excel File

Tags: python, pandas

The following function fails when combining 7 CSV files into one big excel file. 6 of the are under 800kB in size and run without issue. When I introduce the 7th CSV file which have over 800,000 rows and is about 180mb in size the function fails, but without a specific error message. The goal is for each CSV to be written onto a different tab in the Excel. No actual error is being thrown in the logs.

```
import sys
import boto3
from botocore.exceptions import ClientError
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import logging
import xlsxwriter
import datetime
from time import time
import os
from io import BytesIO

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)

# Create the S3 session only once to be reused by multiple functions
session = boto3.session.Session()

def combine_csv_files(s3_client, bucket_name, csv_folder_name):
    try:
        # Get today's date in string format
        today = datetime.date.today()
        date_str = today.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")  # Format the date as YYYY-MM-DD
        
        # List all CSV files in the S3 bucket
        response = s3_client.list_objects_v2(Bucket=bucket_name, Prefix=csv_folder_name)
        csv_files = [
            obj['Key'] 
            for obj in response.get('Contents', [])
            if obj['Key'].endswith('.csv') and date_str in obj['Key']
        ]
        
        if not csv_files:
            logging.error("No CSV files found in the specified folder and date range.")
            return
        
        # Initialize the Excel workbook using pandas ExcelWriter
        excel_file = f'./test_{date_str}.xlsx'
        excel_writer = pd.ExcelWriter(excel_file, engine='xlsxwriter')
        
         # Dictionary to specify the expected data types for specific columns
        expected_data_types = {
            'field1':       str,
            'field2':       str,
            'field3':       str,
            'field4':       str,
            'field5':       str,
            'field6':       str,
            'field7':       str,
            'field8':       str,
            }
        
        chunk_size = 100000  # Adjust the chunk size based on your available memory

        for csv_file in csv_files:
            try:
                # Read the CSV file in chunks
                s3_object = s3_client.get_object(Bucket=bucket_name, Key=csv_file)
                csv_content = s3_object['Body'].read().decode('ISO-8859-1')
                
                logging.info(f"Read the CSV file: {csv_file}")
                # Initialize a list to hold chunks for this CSV file
                chunks = []

                # Use a generator expression to iterate through the chunks and append them to the list
                for chunk in pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(csv_content), dtype=expected_data_types, chunksize=chunk_size):
                    chunks.append(chunk)

                # Concatenate all chunks from this CSV file
                df = pd.concat(chunks, ignore_index=True)

                # Extract the sheet name from the CSV filename
                sheet_name = csv_file.split('/')[-1].split('.')[0]

                # Write the dataframe to the Excel sheet
                df.to_excel(excel_writer, sheet_name=sheet_name, index=False, header=True)

            except Exception as e:
                logging.error(f"Exception occurred while processing CSV file '{csv_file}': {e}")

        # Save and close the Excel workbook
        excel_writer.save()
        logging.info(f"Merged data saved to {excel_file}")
        
        # Upload the Excel file to the S3 bucket
        s3_excel_file = f'test-folder/xlsx/merged_data_file_{date_str}.xlsx'
        s3_client.upload_file(excel_file, bucket_name, s3_excel_file)
        
        # Delete temporary excel file
        os.remove(excel_file)
    except Exception as e:
        logging.error(f"Exception happened during the process: {e}")
```

Comment: In what way does the function fail? Does it fail to create an output file, fail to upload it, does it upload the file but the file in incomplete?